# What does it mean to "find the Fourier series coefficients for the Fourier series over " some interval?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am working through the exercises in Gallagher, "Principles of Digital Communication", specifically exercise 4.1. *This is not homework for a class, but purely self-study*.

The text defines the Fourier series for a time-limited function that is non-zero for $[-\frac{T}{2}, \frac{T}{2}]$ as:
$$u(t) = \begin{cases}
    \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{u}_k \exp{\frac{j2\pi k t}{T}} & \text{for} -\frac{T}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{T}{2} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} $$

Each coefficient $\hat{u}_k$ is given by:
$$\hat{u}_k = \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} u(t) \exp{\frac{-j2\pi k t}{T}} dt$$

From this definition, I understand the interval for the Fourier series to be $[-\frac{T}{2}, \frac{T}{2}]$, so I am assuming that if I were to compute the coefficients over some interval $T=L$, I would substitute $L$ in the expression above.

Now, problem 4.1 in the text asks us to consider $u(t) = \text{rect}(2t)$, and determine a general expression for the Fourier series coefficients for the Fourier series over $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$. From this, I am determining that $T=1$, and  the function $u(t) = \text{rect}(2t)$ is:
$$u(t) = \text{rect} (2t) = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{for} -\frac{1}{2} \leq 2t \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} 
\Rightarrow  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{for} -\frac{1}{4} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{4} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} 
$$

Effectively, I am constraining the limits of integration; however, I do not change the value of $T$ itself. So, for the coefficients, I would be evaluating:

$$ \begin{aligned} \hat{u}_k &= \frac{1}{\mathbf 1} \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \text{rect} (2t) \exp{\frac{-j2\pi k t}{\mathbf 1}} dt \\
 &= \int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{4}}  \exp({-j2\pi k t}) \, dt \\
 &= \frac{1}{\pi k} \sin { \frac {\pi k} {2}} \end{aligned} $$

The question I have is - am I going about this the right way? The next step is to show that this series converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ at the endpoints $\pm\frac{1}{4}$, which I am having a little trouble with, so I want to make sure I am not missing something important.

Thanks!

~*~*~

Edit: continuing the question...

Assuming that the method in the previous part is correct, I am having trouble showing convergence of the Fourier series at the endpoints $t= -\frac{1}{4}$ and $t=+\frac{1}{4}$. My approach is to first substitute the coefficients $\hat{u}_k$ into the expression for $u(t)$ given previously:
$$
u(t)= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{u}_k \exp {\frac{j2\pi k t} {T}}, & \text{for} -\frac{T}{2} \le t \le \frac{T}{2} \\
\displaystyle 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Since the Fourier coefficients were defined over $[-\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2}]$, I take $T=1$. This results in:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u(t) &= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{u}_k \exp {j2\pi k t}, & \text{for} -\frac{1}{2} \le t \le \frac{1}{2} \\
\displaystyle 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi k} \sin {\frac{\pi k} {2} } \exp {j2\pi k t}, & \text{for} -\frac{1}{2} \le t \le \frac{1}{2} \\
\displaystyle 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

I am to evaluate these at the endpoints $t= -\frac{1}{4}$ and $t=+\frac{1}{4}$. So, I substitute each endpoint into the expression above. For example, $t = \frac{1}{4}$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
u\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) &= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi k} \sin {\frac{\pi k} {2} } \exp {j2\pi k \frac{1}{4} } \\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi k} \sin {\frac{\pi k} {2} } \exp {\frac{j\pi k}{2} }
\end{aligned}
$$

In this expression, for $k$ even, the terms in the summand are zero, since the sine becomes zero. For $k$ odd, when I work through it:

$$ \begin{aligned}
k = +1:  &\frac{1}{\pi \cdot(+1)} \sin {\frac{\pi \cdot(+1)} {2} } \exp \left( {j \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot(+1)  } \right) 
= +\frac{1}{\pi} \sin {\frac{+\pi} {2} } \exp {j \frac{+\pi}{2} } = +\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot (+1) \cdot(+j) = +\frac{j}{\pi} \\
k = -1:  &\frac{1}{\pi \cdot(-1)} \sin {\frac{\pi \cdot(-1)} {2} } \exp \left( {j \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot(-1)  } \right) 
= -\frac{1}{\pi} \sin {\frac{-\pi} {2} } \exp {j \frac{-\pi}{2} } = -\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot (-1) \cdot(-j) = -\frac{j}{\pi} \\ \\
k = +3:  &\frac{1}{\pi \cdot(+3)} \sin {\frac{\pi \cdot(+3)} {2} } \exp \left( {j \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot(+3)  } \right) 
= +\frac{1}{3\pi} \sin {\frac{+3\pi} {2} } \exp {j \frac{+3\pi}{2} } = +\frac{1}{3\pi} \cdot (-1) \cdot(-j) = +\frac{j}{3\pi} \\
k = -3:  &\frac{1}{\pi \cdot(-3)} \sin {\frac{\pi \cdot(-3)} {2} } \exp \left( {j \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot(-3)  } \right) 
= -\frac{1}{3\pi} \sin {\frac{-3\pi} {2} } \exp {j \frac{-3\pi}{2} } = -\frac{1}{3\pi} \cdot (-1) \cdot(-j) = -\frac{j}{3\pi} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

And so on. I see cancellations on either side, resulting in zero.

What am I missing? According to the text, it is supposed to converge to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It looks like you're approach is correct. The result will be a periodic function with transitions at $t=\pm\frac{1}{4}$ and a period of $T=1$, so I'm not sure what you mean by "Effectively, I am constraining the limits of integration; however, I do not change the value of T itself".

Comment: I think I am trying to distinguish the interval for the Fourier series from the interval of the  function. So, if the function is defined for the interval $\pm T/4$, for example, that doesn't mean that the Fourier coefficients necessarily have to be computed over that interval - is that correct?

Comment: The $u(t)$ function is defined over all real values of $t$, not some finite interval of the reals. With your definition of $u(t)$, the Fourier series converges to $\underset{\epsilon \to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{u(t-\epsilon)+u(t+\epsilon)}{2}$ in the interval $-\frac{3}{4}<t<\frac{3}{4}$, but the Fourier series converges to a periodic function for all real values of $t$. Assuming one modifies your definition slightly such that $u(-\frac{1}{4})=u(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{2}$, the Fourier series converges to the modified $u(t)$ function in the interval $-\frac{3}{4}<t<\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Good point - $u(t)$ is indeed defined over all real values of $t$, and takes non-zero values in the interval $[-\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}]$. I have a follow-up question, see edits

Comment: Since $u(t)$ is an even function, it only has $\cos$ terms: $\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)}{\pi k} e^{i 2 \pi k t}+\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi (-k)}{2}\right)}{\pi (-k)} e^{i 2 \pi (-k) t}=\frac{2}{\pi} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)}{k} \cos(2 \pi k t)$. The Fourier series is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)}{k} \cos(2 \pi k t)$. The case $k=0$ is as follows: $\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} u(t)\,dt=\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{4}} 1\,dt=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you - I think your method is more straightforward - I must have made a mistake somewhere. One more question - why are you integrating $u(t)$? My understanding is that the Fourier series itself has to converge to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I'm calculating $\frac{1}{2}\ a_0=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}\int\limits_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} u(t)\,dt\right)=\int\limits_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} u(t)\,dt$ (see formulas (13) and (14) at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html).

Comment: I think your mistake is you forgot to account for the constant term $\frac{1}{2}\ a_0$ corresponding to $k=0$.